# Mootools with AJAX onSuccess

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2

I am trying to display a successful message once the form gets sent:

```
$('emeraldForm').addEvent('submit', function(){
        onSuccess: function(){
                alert('df');
    }
    });
```

Comment: this is not even doing ajax... read http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request

Comment: this isn't doing anything at all actually.